# Assistance with claiming French nationality

Tags: france, citizenship

Background: a few years ago, but during my adulthood, my mother (born in the UK) successfully claimed French citizenship, which she had inherited from her father (French, born in France). I (born & living in UK) would like to similarly assert French nationality and acquire a certificate of French nationality, passport, etc.; and hopefully do the same for my wife and child. I am aware that the process will be fairly long and involved, requiring official translation of various documents and one or more appointments at the consulate in London.

I am quite daunted by the whole thing as the information I've found (on uk.ambafrance.org and various private websites) often seems incomplete or inconsistent. My French language skills aren't super strong, and the consulate is a fairly long & expensive journey for me.

I expect that working out the full, detailed, procedure that I'll need to take is beyond the scope of a Stack Exchange question, so:

- **Are there (capable) individuals / companies who can provide this kind of assistance as a service?**
- In particular working out the full sequence of steps I need to take so I can get it right first time, possibly also accompanying & interpreting at the consulate.
- Ideally someone less expensive than a fully qualified French solicitor practising in the UK!

Comment: Have you tried calling the French consulate by telephone?

Comment: @phoog not yet... they have a very bad reputation for 'customer service' and also their website explicitly says they "cannot help you with administrative procedures."

Comment: Hmm.  Well I'll tell you what I'd do:  gather all the documents I need according to uk.ambafrance.org and apply.  The hassle associated with any deficiencies in that application will probably be less than those involved in finding and working with an expediter.  You ought not to need an interpreter at the consulate since a major function of consulates is to provide services in the language of the host country.  Questions about the inconsistencies you've found would certainly be welcome here.